# Dynamic setting language in Golang web framework Iris

Tags: localization, go-iris

> I have these language files:

```
locales/
    en-US/
        a.yaml
        b.yaml
    zh-CN/
        a.yaml
        b.yaml
    DA/
        a.yaml
        b.yaml
```

> set default  language:

```
app.I18n.SetDefault("en-US")
```

> How to set language dynamically according to `l` parameter:

```
www.sete.com/xx/xxx?l=en => set en-US
www.sete.com/xx/xxx?l=cn => set zh-CN
www.sete.com/xx/xxx?l=da => set DA

www.sete.com/xx/xxx?l=NotFound => default en-US
```

> In addition, whenI set a language that doesn't exist:

```
www.sete.com/xx/xxx?l=NotFound
```

I get an error in response like this:

```
{
    "user": "yaml%!(EXTRA string=Tom....)"
}
```

### So , what should I do to better solve these problems? I tried my best, my English is not good, please help me.....

Answer (score 0):

You can find Iris i18n examples at: https://github.com/kataras/iris/tree/master/_examples/i18n

If the language was not found, then the default language's key will be shown instead unless `app.I18N.Strict` is true. If the Strict field is false and the default language has no available key for the translation then the `app.I18n.DefaultMessageFunc` will be fired instead, you can take a look on how to configure what happens if a key does not exist at: https://github.com/kataras/iris/blob/7b6a8f1e26469ab3ae53cfe468d6e5202c75c2a8/_examples/i18n/basic/main.go#L38-L47